# Generate partial strings which have predefined minimum lengths (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, random

I have an initial string Init={ABCDEFGH}. How can I generate 100 partial strings (randomly) from Init string which have these conditions:

```
A pre-defined minimum lengths. 
The order of elements in each partial string should be from 'A' to 'Z'. 
No repeated characters in each partial strings
```

The expected output should be as follows: 100 partial strings, minimum length of each partial string is 5

```
  Output = {'BCEGH';'ACEFG';'ABCDEF';'BCFGH';'BCDEG';....;'ABEFH';'ABCEGH'}
  numel(Output) = 100
```

Comment: You need to specify the probability distribution of lengths. Uniform between minimum and maximum?

Comment: That is a nice idea. May I use normal probability distribution of lengths in this case ? And how ?

Comment: You can't use a normal distribution because it may give negative and non-integer values. You need a discrete distribution, for example uniform (all lenghts within a given range are equally likely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, I started by generating random numbers for the length of each partial string. Then I generated random numbers corresponding to each letter in each string. Then I transferred those numbers into their corresponding letters. The comments should explain the rest.

```
n=100 %// how many samples to take
C='ABCDEFGH' %// take samples from these letters
maxL=numel(C) %// the longest string
minL=5 %// the shortest string
len=randi([minL maxL],[n 1]) %// generate length of each partial string
arrayfun(@(l) C(randsample(1:8,l)),len,'uni',0) %// randomly sample letters to give strings of correct length
```

and `n=4` gives, for example

```
ans = 
    'CFHABEDG'
    'CFHABE'
    'FAHBE'
    'DGHFABE'
```

I'm not sure this is truly random because it assumes that there are the same number of strings of each length, but I don't think this is true. I think `len` should be weighted with respect to the number of strings of each length. I *think* (but I'm not sure) that this should fix that:

```
for i=1:(maxL-minL+1)
    w(i)=factorial(minL-1+i)*nchoosek(maxL,minL-1+i);
end
len=minL-1+randsample(1:(maxL-minL+1),n,true,w./sum(w))
```